# Why do their eyes pop out?

Tags: tropes

If seen this in several series now. When your blowing on something really hard, your eyes come popping out. Is this some sort of symbolism?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: symbol of suffocation???

Comment: @Jiraiya your eyes pop out when you suffocate o-o ?

Comment: lets put it in this way.........try choking yourself [try pressing your throat mildly with ur hands] and then observe the changes in your senses.......while you try to choke,your eyes would be the Ist sense you would observe to pop out

Comment: @Jiraiya guess it is ;o, never got choked before so had no clue :/. Then again, how the hell do you choke whilst blowing a whistle :/

Comment: well my friend that's a million dollar question!!!!!! only anime makers can explain that !!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common trope, not specific to anime. It can be seen in a lot of western cartoons.

The increased air pressure, that is created when blowing very hard, creates a force pushing outwards from your breathing cavities and connected airways. Technically, mouth, nose, ears and eyes share the same complicated pathway, so you could blow your eyes out, if you try hard. The trope in question is just an exaggerated example of it.